# Data frame error when trying to display head

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to display the head 10, but keep getting:

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd     
import numpy as np      

%matplotlib inline    

Pop_By_County = pd.read_csv("TexasPopByCounty2021.csv")
display(Pop_By_County.head(10))
```

Comment: There is likely something else wrong. I'm assuming you're working in a Jupyter notebook? Was `display` ever used as a variable name? Have you tried simply `Pop_By_Country.head(10)` or even just `Pop_By_Country`? The output from simply referencing a DataFrame calls `.head()` anyway, and I believe the default number of rows displayed is 10.

Comment: In your own words, why do you expect `display` to mean anything in this code example? Where do you think its definition is coming from?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

try using>>>

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline

Pop_By_County = pd.read_csv("TexasPopByCounty2021.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(Pop_By_Country)
df.head(10)
```